# Add missing fields to an id form another table

Tags: sql

[Table structure in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liN8q.png)
table 1 shows the permissions
table two assigns the permissions to an id,

I need all the permissions in table one to be assigned to an id
so I need to add permission 3 to id 2 in table 2

I tried using a join to get all the missing columns like such
`

```
SELECT tb1.Desc
    FROM table1 tb1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 tb2
    ON tb1.Desc = tb2.Desc
    WHERE tb2.Desc IS NULL
```

`

but all it did was look for the exact value in the entire table, so because permission 3 exists at id 1, it shows that its in the table and therefore not null. but i was hoping for it to show null where id is 2.

Comment: Don't tag spam dbms'. Tag only the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me, all I had to do was Isolate my selection to the ID i wanted to add to ( in this case ID 2)

```
SELECT tbl1.Desc
FROM Table1 tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select Desc from Tabel2 where ID = @ID) tbl2
ON tbl1.Desc = tbl2.Desc
WHERE tbl1.Desc IS NULL
```